# php Get items from DynamoDB table using a list

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an array of usernames and I want to retrieve from a DynamoDB table all the items that contains usernames that exist in the array.

For Example: if my array is:

`["Foo","Bar"]`

and my table is:

`username | attribute1 | attribute2
Foo      | Value 1    | Value 2
Min      | value1     | value2
Bar      | value  1   | value  2`

Then i want to get the first item and the last item.

I read the documentation for the `scan` operation but it doesn't seem to support this type of request.

Is what I'm asking for possible or am i going to have to iterate over my usernames array and retrieve items for each of them separately?

Comment: username is the hash key of the table?

Comment: @notionquest Yes

Answer (score 1):

Here is the batch get example. Please note that you may need to execute the batch API until UnprocessedKeys is null.

[Batch Get API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html)

```
var params = {
    "RequestItems" : {
        "yourtablename" : {
            "Keys" : [ {
                "username" : "Foo"              
            },{
                "username" : "Bar"              
            } ],
        }
    },
    "ReturnConsumedCapacity" : "TOTAL"
};

docClient.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [Batch Get Item API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) if user name is the Hash Key of the table.

The Batch Get Item API allows you to retrieve multiple items from the DynamoDB table based, provided the keys you provide in the request are part of the HashKey(+RangeKey) or a Global Secondary Index (HashKey (+RangeKey)).

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do that? The username is my hash key but there's no range key.